# OkHttp in android, not seeing network traffic or log responses

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm pretty new to android development so this is one step forward, two steps back every time I figure something out. I'm having trouble making requests using the OkHttp library. I used Volley at first and had that working, but the API endpoints I'm using require a body in some DELETE method requests which Volley does not support.

I have the following in the onStart method of my Activity.

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("<some url>")
        .addHeader("Authorization", "<some token>")
        .build();

new Thread(() -> {
    try(Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
        final String body = response.body() != null ? response.body().string() : null;

        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            if (body != null && !body.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Successful response");
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No body in response");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(final IOException error) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + error.getMessage());
        });
    }
});
```

The network profiler of android studio however, shows nothing going out and the log messages are not logged, but I have no Idea if I'm doing this correctly. I did have it working as mentioned in Volley, but Volley handles the background processes internally so this is my first attempt trying to use this. I had the Log messages outside of runOnUIThread originally as since it wasn't actually touching the UI I didn't think it needed to be in it (that gave no errors, though still no logs)

When the activity runs I do get this output in the debug window, but I don't really know what it means or if it's telling me anything useful about why I'm not seeing the request.

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5afe552
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/etefromplaylis: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/etefromplaylis: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
```

Comment: Hi!! I am using retrofit and I am getting similar message on logcat... did you have the solutions?

Comment: Yes, see the answer I submitted myself. I hadn't invoked start() on the thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just realized I never invoked start() on the Thread. That was it.